# Spring OAuth2 explain Authorization server configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to implement OAuth security and met a problem that for me is not clear enough configuration class.

While implementing `AuthorizationServerConfigurer` i have three configurers:

- `ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer` used to provide the way how and from where to get client details. As an example, it can be service which provides registered clients from the database.

When it comes to  `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer` and `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer` I am not sure what they do or how they should be configured. In the [documentation](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html) it said only:

> `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer`: defines the authorization and
>   token endpoints and the token services.

Maybe someone can explain in simple words what these two configurers do, or what they are used for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`AuthorizationServerConfigurer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/AuthorizationServerConfigurer.html)'s javadoc is more informative than the linked documentation. `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer`, as its name suggests, configures the security of the Authorization Server itself. For example you can override the OAuth endpoints security such as `/oauth/token`, provide an access denied handler or restrict to SSL access. Here are what the documentation says about it:

> Configure the security of the Authorization Server, which means in
>   practical terms the `/oauth/token` endpoint. The `/oauth/authorize`
>   endpoint also needs to be secure, but that is a normal user-facing
>   endpoint and should be secured the same way as the rest of your UI, so
>   is not covered here. **The default settings cover the most common 
>   requirements, following recommendations from the OAuth2 spec, so you
>   don't need to do anything here to get a basic server up and running.**

As for `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer`:

> Configure the non-security features of the Authorization Server
>   endpoints, like token store, token customizations, user approvals and
>   grant types. You shouldn't need to do anything by default, unless you
>   need password grants, in which case you need to provide an
>   `AuthenticationManager`.

Here is a sample from one of my projects:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .tokenStore(jwtTokenStore())
            .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer());
}
```

Here I provided a `JwtTokenStore` as my `TokenStore` and a `AuthenticationManager` since I was using *Password Grants*.

Comment: So shortly: 'AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer' configures how the server is accessed for any requests. While `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer` configures strategy how token will be stored and provided. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

I am using spring-security-oauth, there is a helpful documentation maybe help you :

projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html

Comment: Thnx but I post the same link to documentation.

Comment: Oh sorry I didnt see that. When you use authorization_code grant type, the oauth2 token fetching flow changes,after sending user/pass  you redirect to another url with a autorize code. AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer  has multiple Rest values which is mentioned in documdntation. One of them is /oauth/authorize the url which you configure to refirect after user approves oauth2 resource usage. You can configure these urls by AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer, but it is nof enough for an aughorization server. You must declare an session sharing Strategy with an session store.

Comment: Or a strategy to store your client credentials (InMemory or Jdbc type) or configure your endpoints protections or define token header names and bunch of concepts...

Comment: Every class configures some setting and it is mandatory to be customized...